# How do you make the keyboard appear with no UITextField

Tags: ios, ios5

How would I be able to make the keyboard appear automatically when the viewDidLoad? I also do not want to use the UITextField to make the keyboard appear.

Comment: What do you want to use the keyboard for?

Comment: Yes, what's the reason for showing a keyboard if there's no place to handle the input?

Answer (score 1):

Add a UITextField to your view and call it `[myTextfield becomeFirstResponder];` Then set it to hidden `myTextfield.hidden = true` - so the user will never see the textfield.

Comment: This is what i would do too. Using a private and undocumented class (like @H2CO3 suggests) is a worse solution than having a hidden UITextField IMHO.

Comment: @ErikTjernlund "This is what I would do" and a solution that actually answers the question are two different things. OP asked for a solution without an UITextField and I provided him with one.

Comment: Sure, but the suspicion is that the person asking the question haven't thought through his reasons for not wanting to have a UITextField (for example not thinking about that it could be hidden).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by:

- subclassing UIView (which is a subclass of UIResponder)
- make your UIView Subclas conform to protocol UIKeyInput. To do this add 
  < UIKeyInput >
  in the class declaration and this code to .m file

Add this code:

```
-(BOOL)hasText;
{
    return YES;
}
-(void)insertText:(NSString *)text;
{
    // what to do when a text is inserted
}

-(void)deleteBackward;
{
    // what to do when delete is pressed
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    // return yes if your control can become first responder and show the keyboard
    return YES;
}
```

- create a new instance of this custom view and add it as a subview of the current window (otherwise it won't work)

then, to show the keyboard, you have to simply call [myView becomeFirstResponder];
Just tried and it works well.

**Edit: haven't tried, but it should work subclassing not only uiview, but all kind of objects that are subclasses of UIView and that can be added in the window hierarchy, simply it must conform UIKeyInput protocol**

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know without an UITextField is creating and adding an instance of the (**private, undocumented**) `UIKeyBoard` class. You can find an implementation [here](https://github.com/H2CO3/FileTransfer/blob/master/FTViewController.m), in the `showKeyboard:animated:` method.

Comment: He can do it subclassing UIView and implementing UIKeyInput protocol. Now I post the answer.